# Spring tomcat start exception with StackOverflowError

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, tomcat7

I'm using tomcat 1.7 and it had been worked well.
and today I restart tomcat and got me below StackOverflowError.
The error message seems like log4j loop.
any help will be appreciated.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
        at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:557)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:58)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
        at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
        at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
        at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
        at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
        at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
```

I have log libraries

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.6
org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.6
org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.6
log4j:log4j:1.2.15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependency list (transitive dependencies included) must have both:

- [`log4j-over-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j): a Log4j 1.2 replacement, that sends everything to SLF4j,
- [`slf4j-log4j12`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12): a SLF4j implementation that forwards everything to Log4j 1.2

hence the infinite loop. The `log4j` artifact you mention in your question is not taken into consideration (it must be listed on the classpath after `log4j-over-slf4j`).

Remove `log4j-over-slf4j` and you'll be fine.

Comment: transitive dependency was my problem. I delete log4j-over-slf4j and the loop was gone. thank you ~!

Answer (score 1):

Exclude spring-boot-starter-logging dependency in spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: Remark: this only applies to the 1.x series of Spring Boot. Spring Boot 2.x no longer deals with the configuration of Log4j 1.2.

Comment: Do you have wechat? I want to discuss it with you@Piotr P. Karwasz

Comment: Let's discuss it in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126843/spring-tomcat-start-exception-with-stackoverflowerror).

Comment: I can't get into this chat room@Piotr P. Karwasz

Comment: Unfortunately you need at least 20 reputation.

Comment: Ha ha, in fact, I didn't register for long@Piotr P. Karwasz

Comment: Make a friend? I'm new to Java @Piotr P. Karwasz